# Swift Initializer by Class Name causes Error: Class is of type "Protocol"

Tags: swift

I have the following 2 classes and a protocol: WeatherFacade and WeatherObject, which is of type of the protocol ModelObjects (WeatherObject conforms to ModelObjects and is type ModelObjects). I want to create an instance of the WeatherObject by it's name but I get error:

> 'init' is a member of the type; use 'type(of: ...)' to initialize a new object of the same dynamic type

The WeatherFacade class consists of a Networking Class and a WeatherObject properties and init like so:

```
let networking: Networking
let model: ModelProtocol

init(model: String) {
    self.networking = Networking()


    let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String

    let className: ModelProtocol = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(model)") as! ModelProtocol

    self.model = className.init()//error here
}
```

ModelProtocol looks like this

```
protocol ModelProtocol{

    func parse<T: Decodable>(data: Data) throws -> Array<T>?

}
```

WeatherObject is nothing at this point, just a classname that conforms to ModelProtocol like so:

```
class WeatherModel: NSObject, ModelProtocol {}
```

The class in question uses the standard `init()`. How can I get an instance of my WeatherObject by passing in the name?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Please show all the definitions of relevant classes and protocols.

Comment: @OOPer edits added as requested

Comment: You cannot initialize a protocol. The protocol is a confirmation for the compiler that the adopting type has implemented the properties and function of the protocol, nothing else. `NSClassFormString` is very *objective-c-ish*. There are better native ways like generics or protocols with associated types.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
class WeatherModel: NSObject, ModelProtocol {}
```

causes error. You should better try to show enough code to reproduce your issue.

---

Anyway, you have two major problems.

First, this declaration `let className: ModelProtocol` declares `className` as an instance conforming to the protocol `ModelProtocol`. It's not the declaration for a type.

Second, there is no default initializer in Swift. When you want to call `init()` on a type variable conforming to a protocol, the protocol needs to declare `init()`.

So, your protocol should be something like this:

```
protocol ModelProtocol{

    func parse<T: Decodable>(data: Data) throws -> Array<T>?

    init()

}
```

You need to add `required` initializer to conform to it:

```
class WeatherModel: NSObject, ModelProtocol {

    func parse<T: Decodable>(data: Data) throws -> Array<T>? {
        //...
        return [/*...*/]
    }

    override required init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

And then, you can write something like this:

```
init(model: String) {
    self.networking = Networking()

    let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String

    let classType: ModelProtocol.Type = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(model)") as! ModelProtocol.Type

    self.model = classType.init()
}
```